# NativeScript - import filesystem unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, nativescript, importerror

I want to check a config file before my NativeScript app start to set global variable. 
So i put in my app.js file :

```
import * as fs from "tns-core-modules/file-system";
```

But the app don't start and i got an error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import....
```

I'm starting using NativeScript maybe there is a file where i need to import all i want in my app but i don't find where ?

My complete app.js file :

```
import * as fs from "tns-core-modules/file-system";
require("./bundle-config");
const application = require("application");
application.start({ moduleName: "home/home-page" });
```

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript for Android uses V8 engine which seems to not support ES6 import syntax as of now, so you must go with require syntax if you are using JavaScript for development.

If you are really interested in using ES6 syntax / features, try migrating to TypeScript or setup transpilers like babel.

Comment: Thank's i understand